# Styling child custom menu pages

Tags: menus, css

I have a custom menu created using Appearance > Menus which contains top level and child pages.

I would like to be able to indent my child level pages to give some sort of visual hierarchy to the content.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some digging around led me to find that all the items were marked up with the class `sub-menu` which I was able to style in the CSS.